# heap tree - complexity to output a sorted list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heapsort

there is an unsorted list of numbers and a heap tree is constructed out of them.

What is the time complexity of outputting a sorted list of numbers from the heap tree that is already constructed?

(Note: the nodes does not need to be removed from the tree to get current min/max, looking for an efficient way to traverse the heap tree and output the sorted list of numbers)

Comment: As Grigor said it will take O(nlogn) unless you can use Counting Sort (in which case you do not need a heap).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a tree in sorted order using heap properties (Cormen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110844/print-a-tree-in-sorted-order-using-heap-properties-cormen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same as sorting the list initially - O(nlogn). This is because heapifying the list takes O(n) time, and it's impossible to print sorted sequence out of the heap faster than O(nlogn), because it'd mean it's possible to sort any sequence faster than O(nlogn) (by heapifying and then outputing), which is proved to be wrong.

Comment: While this only posits a lower bound, I don't understand why it got downvoted. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question to [Print a tree in sorted order using heap properties (Cormen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110844/print-a-tree-in-sorted-order-using-heap-properties-cormen/8111300#8111300). There is an illustration provided in the original question of why it is an `nlogn` operation and not `logn`.